# Existen Skins, Themes, Templates, Plantillas,... Para controles en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, template, theme

Supongo que sí, y que además existen gratuitos, pero no los encuentro.

Estoy buscando eso, temas para mis windows forms en c#. Ya he visto que pueden hacerse como clases en el proyecto y, como carezco de diseñadores gráficos para mi aplicación, he pensado escoger algún tema o plantilla en concreto ya diseñado para darle aspecto visual a los botones, data grid views, etc... sin calentarme mucho la cabeza y perder tiempo en el diseño.

Podéis decirme alguna página donde poder descargarlos y que traiga manual para aplicarlos??
Uso Visual Studio 2017 Professional Edition.

Answer (score 2):

El mejor de todos, para mi gusto es Telerik. Tienen excelentes controles.
Tambiés existen controles gratuitos pero de menor calidad. Aquí te dejo una lista de algunos:

1. [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx).
2. [Infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms).
3. [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/).